# My java program is throwing java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for some AWT classes what do I do?

Tags: java, filesystems

when I ran the Java debugger, I found this "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun/awt/resources/spi/awtProvider" and "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.6.10-hotspot\conf\accessibility.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)" I think I know why, my data storage was running low so I moved my programs to a different drive, is that why it can't find java API classes? how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to fix this.

- `sun.awt.resources.spi.awtProvider` is a class name that is automatically generated as a possible resource bundle provider. If the class is not found it will be ignored.

See the source at https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/java/awt/Toolkit.java#L1416:

```
            try {
                resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("sun.awt.resources.awt");
            } catch (MissingResourceException e) {
                // No resource file; defaults will be used.
            }
```

- `accessibility.properties` is an optional file that can be used to configure assistive technologies. If this file is not found nothing changes.

According to the sources at https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11u/blob/master/src/java.desktop/share/classes/java/awt/Toolkit.java#L423:

```
                try {
                    File propsFile = new File(
                        System.getProperty("java.home") + sep + "conf" +
                        sep + "accessibility.properties");
                    FileInputStream in =
                        new FileInputStream(propsFile);

                    // Inputstream has been buffered in Properties class
                    properties.load(in);
                    in.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // System-wide accessibility properties file does
                    // not exist;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many such exceptions during normal startup of a Java program.  To avoid stopping at each, turn off the generic "Caught Exceptions" breakpoint in your debugger until execution reaches your own code.